# Best way to hand a WAR file from one Maven project to another, to use with Embedded Jetty?

Tags: maven, maven-2, solr, jetty

I thought this was simple, but having problems:

- Project1 is of type war.  It creates an entire webapp .war file, including some Apache modules (solr/lucene), and some of our custom code.
- Project2 is an existing application.  It needs to launch embedded Jetty to do queries against Project1's war file.  (see code below)

Main Problem:

- When Project2 instantiates Jetty, it needs to pass in the full path to the WAR file, but this changes each time.  Maven adds version number stuff to Project1's war file.

Assemblies to the Rescue?

- I'm able to get a custom assembly to work, but can't get rid of the versioning stamp from Project1.

But I always wind up with Project1-1.4.1-20120530.233546-2.war.  It's in a more convenient place, but the name is still weird.

Jetty code in Project2:

```
    // Context
    WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext();
    webapp.setContextPath("/");
    String jettyHome = System.getProperty( "jetty.home", ".." );
    String fullWarName = ...;    // Project1's WAR file. This path always changes
    webapp.setWar( fullWarName );
    // Server
    Server server = new Server( kPort ); // TODO: get from config
    server.setHandler(webapp);
    server.start();
    server.join();
```

Other considerations:

- I realize there is a maven-jetty plugin, but I don't believe that's appropriate here.  It seems to be targeted at Unit tests, and also our application stack doesn't use maven at runtime to launch services.
- I'm also aware that Solr has a fully embedded version that doesn't require a web container, but that's been deprecated for a while and not a good idea to use.

Is there a better way to refactor this project?  Maybe this isn't "the maven way" ?

Comment: Have you tried specifying a build name in project 1 - inside its pom add `<build><finalName>Project1</finalName></build>`. That should result in a war file called Project1.war.

Comment: @nickdos thanks, that addressed one of the issues!  Had a bit of a setback in Project2, still chasing that down.

Comment: FYI @nickdos it's really odd, the output of Project1 was indeed project1.war as I asked.  BUT in the consuming project, Project2, I still see Project1-1.2.3-20120605.165943-3.war  I did a clean and rechecked.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I didn't need an assembly (advice I had got internally), instead there's something easier in the main pom.  Also, having the war unpacked here turned out to be a nice idea.

At the top of Project1's pom.xml I have:

```
 <groupId>com.my.group</groupId>
 <artifactId>project-one</artifactId>
 <version>1.2.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <packaging>war</packaging>
```

This goes near the bottom of Project2's pom.xml

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>unpack-webapp</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>unpack</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
          <artifactItems>
           <artifactItem>
            <groupId>com.my.group</groupId>
            <artifactId>project-one</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>war</type>
            <overWrite>true</overWrite>
            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/webapps/project-one</outputDirectory>
           </artifactItem>
         </artifactItems>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Then when launching Jetty I have:

```
webapp.setWar( "target/webapps/project-one" );
```

I still think there might be issues with some Jetty settings, but I think this is the right direction.